# Why do I keep getting "Safe handle has been closed" error for even a simple Hello World Universal Windows Platform Application in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

I keep getting the following error whenever I open the MainPage.xaml by the xaml editor.
I actually get this error for almost all of my apps.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
Safe handle has been closed
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Go back to a previous version that didn't get the error and start modifying till you find what is causing it.

Comment: I get this error for almost all of my apps.

Comment: do you mean first when you start?

Comment: I mean when I open the solution and the  MainPage.xaml.

Comment: Can the designer load successfully?

Comment: No. The designer does not load and gives this error.

Comment: I request someone to please answer this question soon as I need Visual Studio working for code.fun.do . It is urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it fixed by a weird method.

I switched from developer mode to sideloading enabled mode and tried to reload the designer which failed saying I need a developer license to do so. I then reverted back to developer mode and again tried to reload the designer. This time it worked.

Now I have to perform the above steps for every project which failed to load(including new projects) to load them successfully.

Once the XAML designer loads successfully for a project, it will surely load successfully every time subsequently.

Comment: Worth a shot, I guess. Even though I have this problem for Win8.1 projects only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar issue with you on [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1645171/visual-studio-2015-xaml-designer-fails-with-system-exception), and it is solved by upgrade the visual studio. You can try solutions in that link, please also try the following steps to try to resolve your issues:

- Restart the machine.
- Check the [Visual Studio 2015 System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs) to see if your environment meet the requirements. If it doesn't meet requirement, you might need to upgrade it.
- Create a new blank UWP project to see if it will work.
- Try to [repair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#Repairing%20Visual%20Studio) your Visual Studio.
- Re-install the [windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

If all above cannot resolve your issue I'm afraid you need to re-install your visual studio.

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi sad to hear that. Even re-install the visual studio? How about a new blank WPF project?